# Gradient overlay is in front of button - not clickable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a gradient overlay on my grid elements.

Everything as actually working as it should, but there is one big problem. On the backend of my CMS system the overlay is in front of a very central button. That is the button I click when I have to change the code on the site.

I do not have access and I am not allowed to overwrite existing functions etc. The whole problem is the following class:

```
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    transition:all .3s ease;
    /* opacity:0; */
    transition:1.9s;
    background: #00b1bab8;
  }
```

If I outcomment `opacity:0;` I can click on the button. When the opacity is active, I cannot click on the button. It is also not possible to set a z-index, because that is not working. Mostly I am afraid of affecting all other pages if I start overwriting classes etc.

Is there anyone who have an alternative idea or solution on how I can have the gradient effect, but still use the backend of the CMS system. Is it some javascript there is needed, or is there just an easy solution that I am overseeing?

I posted some of the code there is mostly relevant - here I am thinking the overlay classes.

```css
.image-overlay {
    position:relative;
  }
  .overlay {
    position:absolute;
    transition:all .3s ease;
    opacity:0;
    transition:1.9s;
    background: #00b1bab8;
  }
  .image-overlay:hover .overlay {
    opacity:1;
  }
  .overlayFade {
    background: rgba(27, 27, 27, 0.5);
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 35px;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="mk row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="mk row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 margin_bottom">
                      <a href="#">
                          <div class="image-overlay">
                              <div class="overlay overlayFade"></div>
                              <img src="https://vouzalis.dk/test.jpg" alt="John Doe" class="img-responsive"></img>
                              <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-left">
                                  <h2 class="light-font">Company gear</h2>
                                  <p class="light-font">Se vores udvalg af klasse Company merchandise</p>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="mk row">
                          <div class="col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
                              <a href="#">
                                  <div class="image-overlay">
                                      <div class="overlay overlayFade"></div>
                                      <img src="https://company.dk/Static/Cms/c3a9d70d-8a4c-4121-bb01-4144125708ab.jpg" alt="John Doe" class="img-responsive"></img>
                                      <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-right">
                                          <h3 class="light-font">5 par solbriller</h3>
                                          <p class="light-font">5 brændvarme tilbud</p>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </a>  
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="mk row">
                          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 margin_bottom">
                              <a href="#">
                                  <div class="image-overlay">
                                      <div class="overlay overlayFade"></div>
                                      <img src="https://company.dk/Static/Cms/ec68cc2e-f3f1-485f-bbb5-f3b22a052a80.jpg" alt="Følg Company på Snapchat" class="img-responsive"></img>
                                      <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-left">
                                          <h5 class="light-font">Motorsport kasket</h5>
                                          <p class="light-font">Stilet kasket til når solen er skarp</p>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 margin_bottom">
                              <a href="#">
                                  <div class="image-overlay">
                                      <div class="overlay overlayFade"></div>
                                      <img src="https://company.dk/Static/Cms/74ce064e-942d-4d60-8f2a-5238e40f9a22.jpg" alt="John Doe" class="img-responsive"></img>
                                      <div class="inner-wrapper centered">
                                          <!--<button class="btn btn-success" style="background-color: transparent;">Læs mere</button>-->
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </a>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: z-index property might help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Z-index will not help in this situation. It will affect around 50.000 pages in the CMS system.

Comment: I don't understand the question, but if `z-index` isn't the way to go, maybe find an alternative to the gradient?

Comment: I didn't get the question. Where's your central button in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pointer-events: none;` on your overlay to disable any pointer event and effectively "click through" it. Note that this will not work on IE10 or below.